# Really basic moq example fails

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying out Moq, and I've gotten stuck in a very basic example. I want to mock a very simple interface IInput:

```
namespace Example
{
    public interface IInput
    {
        int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This seems like a very easy job. However, I get a compilation error when I try to mock it in the following test code:

```
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace FirstEniro._Test
{

    [TestFixture]
    class TestFirstClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestConstructionOk()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IInput>();
            mock.Setup(r => r.SomeProperty).Returns(3);

            var x = new FirstClass(mock);

            Assert.That(x, Is.EqualTo(3));
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says "cannot convert from `Moq.Mock<Example.IInput>` to `<Example.IInput>`. 
I can't see what I am doing wrong. Please help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Object` property of mock to retrieve instance of mocked object.

```
   var x = new FirstClass(mock.Object);
```

In Moq framework `Mock` is not an instance of what you are mocking (like in Rhino Mocks).

Comment: Thanks. You just pinpointed my problem: I am "polluted" by Rhino Mocks experience :-)

Comment: @Morten that's because I had same problem when switched from Rhino to Moq :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object` property on `Mock` instance to get the actual mocked object.

```
var x = new FirstClass(mock.Object);
```

`Mock` class is used for settings up methods / verifications. 
You need to use `Object` accessor due to C# compiler restriction. You can vote for having it lifted on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=318122) (see a note in [QuickStart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)).